# Как правильно отображать сессии в view? (Ruby on Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

В контроллере сохраняю результаты ответа от API в сессии. Но при попытке отобразить выводит пустое поле

home_controller.rb

```
auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
session[:current_user] = { :nickname => auth.info['nickname'],
  :image => auth.info['image'],
  :uid => auth.uid }
```

index.html.slim

```
- if session.key? :current_user
h3 Current user:
= image_tag(session[:current_user][:image])
p = session[:current_user][:nickname]
p = session[:current_user][:uid]
```

Высвечиваются пустые строки. Когда пытаюсь сделать debug - всё выводит

```
= debug session[:current_user]
---
nickname: text
image: url
uid: text
```

Может я неправильно вызываю?

Comment: Ты уверен что у тебя `auth.info['nickname']` не возвращает пустое значение. Может он пуст ещё в контроллере? Попробуй использовать дебаг.

Comment: @AndrewTymchenko Да, уверен, я сделал так session[:nickname] = auth.info['nickname'] Всё работает и выводится в вьюхе (извиняюсь за говнокод, но надо просто пртетстить API)

Comment: попробуй не использовать такую форму ключа `session[:current_user]`,а `session[:auth_user_api]`.

Comment: @AndrewTymchenko спасибо за совет)